# Adding datalabels - matplotlib barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrameGroupBy object that I am ploting like so...

```
grouped.sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

which gives...

[image]

but I would like something more like this...

[image]

I just want to know how to add data labels to each column and possibly a table as well?

Comment: what version of your Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add value labels on top of the bar plot, you can loop through the columns in each index and use `text` to *show* the values, something like this:

```
df = DataFrame(rand(3,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
ax = df.plot(table=True, kind='bar', title='Random')
for i, each in enumerate(df.index):
    for col in df.columns:
        y = df.ix[each][col]
        ax.text(i, y, y)
```

You may want to adjust the text labels coords to have a better alignment etc.

---

To show the grid table, `pandas` has table support from 0.14+.

You can read more about [Plotting table HERE](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#plotting-tables)

> Plotting with matplotlib table is now supported in DataFrame.plot()
>   and Series.plot() with a table keyword. The table keyword can accept
>   bool, DataFrame or Series. The simple way to draw a table is to
>   specify table=True. Data will be transposed to meet matplotlib’s
>   default layout.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df = DataFrame(rand(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)   # Hide Ticks
df.plot(table=True, ax=ax)
```

> Also, you can pass different DataFrame or Series for table keyword.
>   The data will be drawn as displayed in print method (not transposed
>   automatically). If required, it should be transposed manually as below
>   example.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)   # Hide Ticks
df.plot(table=np.round(df.T, 2), ax=ax)
```